# How can I add 'editable' checkbox in ASP.NET?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, checkbox, dynamic

I want to implement something like this
[image]
If the 'Other' checkbox is selected, the text adjacent to it become editable OR a new checkbox is added where the text of the checkbox is editable depending on user choice. Is it implementable in ASP.NET?

### What I have tried

I have added checkbox on the fly using jQuery but those are not accessible in ASp.NET code and hence I can't use it. I have also looked on onselectedindex event but could not find a way where a checkbox can be added to CheckBoxList 'with editable text'.

```
Your favour subject?<br><br>
<input type=checkbox > <label>Physics</label>
<input type=checkbox > <label>chemistry</label>
<input type=checkbox > <label>Math</label>
<input type=checkbox > <label>Other</label> _______________________
```

I want something very close to [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jrtcqq3p/), the problem is jQuery stuff is not accessible on server side. I think I should be able to just Ajax to send the newly created checkbox along with old checkbox to database where they will be saved, but that will make my logic complicated as I have other controls on the page as well.

Comment: First off are all these checkboxs link to one input? As in are you just posting a string with all values attached separated by commas? Or are all checkbox their own input with their own ID?

Comment: @Canvas Yes, they belong to one in put. I am using CheckBoxList control. Each checkbox is stored in database in a seperate column though. Not using CSV format. I can consider though.

Comment: actually, if you are submitting your form, the newly added controls are accessible from the request object instead of being accessible by just using the name

Comment: Hmm that's a good thought. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the `CheckBoxList` Control. Add that to the page and add an `OnSelectedIndexChanged` to the CheckBoxList and set `AutoPostBack` to `true`.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Physics" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Chemistry" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Math" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Other" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Enabled="false"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

And then in code behind

```
protected void CheckBoxList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Visible = false;
    RequiredFieldValidator1.Enabled = false;

    foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
    {
        if (item.Value == "0" && item.Selected == true)
        {
            TextBox1.Visible = true;
            RequiredFieldValidator1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: However I want checkboxes not radio buttons because user can select multiple options. I am afraid your code does not address that part.

Comment: I've modified my answer. Somewhere along the line I changed checkboxes into radiobuttons...

Comment: This might work but already  implemented this solution in jQuery which works fine (without page refresh), the issue is, I want to add another checkbox when other is is already used, so user can keep on adding 'other'. This is where the problem becomes tricky? Do you think there is neat way of doing it? I need this done asap and I can't find a proper solution. Thx